# If the Diving question of a similar format is allowed, why is Surfing not allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

### 1. If the diving question of a similar format is allowed, why is Surfing not allowed?

We have **where-on-earth**, **destination** tags, so I modeled question after reading these 2 & more

---

### **[Where's the cheapest place in the world for a beginner to learn diving?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21435/wheres-the-cheapest-place-in-the-world-for-a-beginner-to-learn-diving?rq=1)**

**Tags:** *budget*, **where-on-earth**, **destinations**, *diving*

---

### [What places offer both good scuba diving and surfing?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/what-places-offer-both-good-scuba-diving-and-surfing?rq=1)

**Tags:** beaches, *diving*, **destinations**, *surfing*

---

### 2. What would the mods like me to do, to have it get approval as the Diving thread?

---

### **Inexpensive beach locations to learn surfing as a newbie?**

Travel SE - 
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53803/best-inexpensive-beaches-season-for-beginner-to-learn-surfing

Outdoors SE - 
https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9316/inexpensive-beach-locations-to-learn-surfing-as-a-newbie

---

Please share your thoughts on the above 1 & 2.
I appreciate your help & feedback, but I based the question on the Diving thread and hence was defending it with other stances & points.

**Instead of focusing on whether it should be on Travel or Outdoors or what was wrong**, lets drop that and **focus on how it can be shaped for approval by mods like the diving thread.** 
Let's see how we can take inputs from Diving question and applying it to the Surfing one.

I think it will garner good answers over time once framed correctly.

Comment: This post seems to indicate that you have completely misunderstood what is meant by "too broad" and "opion based". I recoomend you go read the full descriptions of these on the help centre, not just the titles.

Comment: @CMaster - How does the diving Question - linked above - stand and Surfing wont?

Comment: @CMaster - The question was Cleaned up & Refined to fit similar to the Diving question why has it been "taken back to unrevised" state?

Comment: Pinging me on a question 4 years old to come to a meta isn't the best practice btw ;) Similarly, comparing current questions to ancient ones (the site is only just over 4 years old) is problematic - rules have changed since then, so questions that might have been answered back then get closed now, and vice-versa. I think the answers below are doing a good job of helping out for now...

Answer (score 5):

No, the problem with your question is **not** that it is "well researched, summarized detailed, [and doesn't] need clarification via commenting."  Such questions are by no means frowned on. (What's more, I think you knew that and are deliberately being rude, not a good start to working stuff out on meta. But anyway.) Your question is being frowned on because it asks others to make a decision. Instead, you should be asking multiple questions to let **you** make a decision.

- Which beaches in [country you're considering] have good surfing and inexpensive accomodation (hostels etc)
- How consistent is the weather in [specific location you're considering]? Is it possible to have a week's surfing trip spoiled by bad weather?

Slowly you gather all the information - from internet searches, from crisp questions here - and then you make your decision. You can't ask us to make it for you. And the unrelated factoids don't belong all in the same question.

Comment: I am not being rude. People voted to close the question without due reason. The one person who commented and I have defended against those comments. 

And no, its not asking others to make a decision. Are you saying there can be only ONE right answer to finding a destination that fits a certain parameter? 

It is stupid to make 2 questions. I could do that, but a person who knows X beach is good for beginners will know during what season it is. 

The answer is VALID only during the SEASON when the BEGINNER friendly WAVES/WATERS & BEGINNER friendly BEACH/EARTH come together.

Comment: Updated title and direction of question/ statement/ the stance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is either opinion based or too broad.

Either, you ask for "best" and people will disagree over what "best" means. You can try and specify it down, but I doubt you'll be able to get over having an important opinion-determined element. Opinion based does not mean that the answers will have opions in them "the teachers are sooo sexy". It means that where is chosen to be "best" will be driven by the answerer's opinion.

Or you just ask (as initally) "where can you" which may well have *hundreds* of possible answers. Noone is likley to have the knowledge to sum them all up in a single (or even 2 or 3) answers. That's what considered too broad. "Too broad" does not mean, as you seem to think, "interests too few people". Too broad means that the scope of answers is too big to provide a definitive answer.

It's a good item for a discussion - maybe tripadvisor forums could help you out. It's a bad one for a *ranked* Q&A format.

Comment: How does the diving Question - linked above - stand and Surfing wont?

Comment: There are probably very very few locations worldwide to satisfy Alex's request. Europe, Australia, Brazil, South Africa and the US are excluded since they're expensive to live for a few months. I'd say the list of sandy locations with good surfing outside these locales is maybe a dozen items long.

Comment: Updated title and direction of question/ statement/ the stance.

Comment: Jonathan - trust me, the list is immense! You can travel the world for years and hardly visit the list of good surf beaches.

Answer (score 4):

Alex - I am the mod who originally closed your question on Outdoors.SE. I probably shouldn't have tried to migrate it here, but was travelling, working on my mobile and thought it could perhaps fit here.

The problem, as others have pointed out, isn't that what you are asking is wrong, it is just entirely unsuited to Stack Exchange.

I pointed you at a good surfing question on Outdoors, that focused on the things you should look for in a surfing location, but asking "where should I go?" is opinion based and too broad.

Your approach at trying to argue the case is probably not helping you either - the folks who have already commented and answered have tried to be polite and helpful, giving guidance - but you seem to be arguing that they couldn't possibly know, and that only a surfer can answer.

I have been a surfer for over 20 years, and a sailor for 36 years. Does that help in how I moderate sites? No. It may help me provide answers, but helping the site run effectively is a task that mods who never set foot on a board can do.

Comment: I apologize if it was perceived as being rude. I based my question on the diving thread hence I have been trying to defend it. 
1. If the diving question of a similar format is allowed, why is Surfing not allowed? 
2.  What would you & mods like me to do, to have it get approval as the Diving thread?

Comment: Updated the above question. Please help with 1 & 2 above.

Comment: For 1 - I think the diving one should also be closed. You can see the answers there disagree with each other, and the commentary shows there was a lot of disagreement. Also, as sites grow, you may find that questions which were allowed in the past would not be accepted now. Sometimes they are kept for historic reasons. Sometimes they are closed. If you look at the answers there, and here, you can see there is no answer to your question - surfing has no "best" location. You could possibly get a "biggest wave" question, but best is not measurable objectively

Answer (score 3):

**Best inexpensive beaches & season for beginner to learn Surfing?**

Answer 1: the best beach for that is on the east coast of Africa (per [Endless Summer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060371/))

Answer 2: the best beach for that is at La Jolla (perfect break)

Answer 3: the best beach for that is at Easter Island

Answer 4: Topsail beach in North Carolina has it all dude!

Which of these is the single, factually correct answer?

Comment: FW - 1. Should I remove "best" from the question? Put 'Suitable' or 'Good' instead? 
2. Are you saying every SE / Travel SE question can have only ONE SINGLE PERFECT correct answer? 

Travel is not BOOLEAN LOGIC. The earth is huge and when asking for  "inexpensive learner beaches" if there are few Good Answers rather than a perfect one .. is that wrong? Is that Taboo on SE? 

How many questions on SE do you see with only ONE perfect answer? 

There are usually more than one answer in LIFE & TRAVEL. 

In SuperUser/ Tech, you can probably weed out from few GOOD answers and maybe pick 1

Comment: @GayotFow there are probably very very few locations worldwide to satisfy Alex's request. Europe, Australia, Brazil, South Africa and the US are excluded since they're expensive to live for a few months.

Comment: In superuser, all answers (that aren't down voted) should be factually correct. The ranking helps indicate which wasy is best to use. In travel, we could list a great, great many answers for this question, and voting is going to be driven by how long the answer was up for, and OPINION weighting. Not a good fit for the format.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Yes, there are few places that fit. Probably less places than the Diving question.

Comment: @CMaster - I disagree. There are not so many answers. Bottomline: How does the diving Question - linked above - stand and Surfing wont?

Comment: Updated title and direction of question/ statement/ the stance.